# The port of the container running inside the kubernetes pod could not be connected to the load balancer

Tags: kubernetes

I am using the below yaml file in which I am running 3container inside a pod using a tomcat image, I have given the service type as loadbalancer, but I am not able to access the tomcat in the external browser.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: tomcat
  labels:
    name: tomcat
---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  namespace: tomcat
  name: tomcat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: jpetstores1
        image: petstoremysql2:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
        - name: sname
          value: petstore1
                                 
      - name: jpetstores2
        image: petstoremysql2:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
        - name: sname
          value: petstore2    
        
      - name: jpetstores3
        image: petstoremysql2:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
        - name: sname
          value: petstore3 
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: tomcat
  name: tomcat-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: tomcat
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 81
    targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer

---


apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: tomcat
  namespace: tomcat
spec:
  maxReplicas: 3
  minReplicas: 1
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: tomcat
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 80
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: memory
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 97

---
apiVersion: policy/v1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: tomcat-pdb1
  namespace: tomcat
spec:
  minAvailable: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: tomcat
```

**Note :If only one container is running in it, I can access it in the browser**

I need to run all three containers in the same pod with the same image, and access the tomcat in the browser through the port given in the loadbalancer.

Comment: You cannot bind to the same port from multiple containers within a pod.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by running 3 containers in the same pod? Ideally they should be in separate pods. The only difference I see is the `sname` env values.

Comment: Hi sibtain..... I want a simple configuration where I am creating multiple instances of Tomcat and load balancing to them. Say 3 instances to start with and then can go up to 5.

Answer (score 1):

> I want a simple configuration where I am creating multiple instances of Tomcat and load balancing to them. Say 3 instances to start with and then can go up to 5.

You achieve this by using a single `Deployment` manifest, with **one** instance of your container.

You can adjust the number of replicas to 3, by changing (from `1` to `3`) this line in your `Deployment`:

```
spec:
  replicas: 3
```

If you want to use the `HorizontalPodAutoscaler` and scale from 3 to 5, you can use these values in the manifest:

```
spec:
  maxReplicas: 5
  minReplicas: 3
```

Comment: Ty. This did work and we got 3 pods with the same container. Now I have another question for you. I want to reuse pod names e.g. I have 3 pods and they are initially created with names like p1, p2, p3. Now if two p1 and p3 go down and new pods are created, I want to have same names for the new pods - p1 and p3 rather creating an arbitrary new name. We save configuration tied to server name. I appreciate your help very much.

Comment: @AnandArc you should connect using the `Service` name - not using the name of the pods. Mark this answer as "accepted" if it solved your problem.

Comment: I am able to connect. No issues there. But I want to reuse pod names. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I can put this question about reusing pod names separately if that is better.

Comment: @AnandArc pod names are intended to be unique. If you are connecting to the Service, there is really no use for controlling the name. Or for what reason do you need to control the name, aren't the app stateless?

Comment: We deploy our agent on each pod and monitor pod/apps etc. Agent inherits the name from the pod. Now we can configure special monitoring for a particular pod. If the pod names keep all our configuration tied to an agent goes away. Hope I clarified ok.

Comment: @AnandArc it sounds like a configuration not compatible with Kubernetes. I would re-design that solution. Use e.g. Kubernetes Labels instead of pod names.